# Flux: async communication with websockets

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to arrange async server-client communication with websockets and vanilla flux architecture. There is an excellent article about "[Async Server-Side Communication with the Flux Architecture](http://mjw56.github.io/handling-asynchronous-data-flow-in-flux/index.html)". I gonna implement it analogue with SockJS and ES6 promises:

***ActionCreator.js***     *- it's the same but moved to ES6*

```
import * as constants from ('../constants/constants'),  
import TodoService = require('../services/todo-service');

class ActionCreator {  

  addTodo(text) {
    var that = this;
    service.addTodo({text: text}).then(function(todo) {
        that.dispatch(constants.ADD_TODO, todo);
    });
  }
}

export default new ActionCreator();
```

**services/todo-service.js** *- even shorter*

```
import WebSocketWrapper from 'WebSocketWrapper';

class TodoService {

    addTodo(todo) {
        //maybe do something with todos before send them to the server
        return WebSocketWrapper.send(todo);
    }
}

export default new TodoService();
```

***WebSocketWrapper.js***

```
/**
 * Due fact that SockJS provide raw websocket API and do not implement pub/sub, we need to do wrapper, which will corellate request/response
 */

import SockJS from 'sockjs';
import selectn from 'selectn';

var reqId = 1; 
const responseDeffers = {};

class WebSocketWrapper {

    constructor(url) {
        this.ws = new SockJS(url);
        this.ws.onopen = this.onOpen;
        this.ws.onmessage = this.onMessage;
        this.ws.onclose = this.onClose;
        this.ws.onerror = this.onError;
    }, 

    onMessage(message) {
        let requestId = selectn('message.data.request_id');
        if (!requestId) return;
        //resolve or reject the promise which is kept in ActionCreator
        if (message.data.result === 'Ok') resolveRequest(requestId, message);
        else rejectRequest(requestId, message.error);
    },

    /**
     * Return Promise, which will be resolved/rejected on server response with the same requestId
     */
    send(request) {  
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            //cache resolve/reject function to be able to invoke themn on server response
            responseDeffers[reqId++] = {
                resolve: res,
                reject: rej
            };
            //send message via websockets
            if (this.ws.readyState == this.ws.OPEN) {
                this.ws.send(JSON.stringify(request));
            } else {
                reject('Websocket connection is closed');
            }
        });
    },

    resolveRequest(requestId, message) {
        let response = JSON.parse(message.data);
        responseDeffers[request_id].resolve(response);
    },

    rejectRequest(requestId, message) {
        responseDeffers[requestId].reject(message);
    }

    onOpen() {},

    oClose() {},

    onError(e) {}
}

export default new WebSocketStore(ENV.props.url);
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question after receiving answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Mast ok< I just want to share this reference for further code reviews. I'll accept Joseph's answer

Comment: If there are enough changes made, there's nothing wrong with posting your new code as a separate follow-up question. Adding links in the new and this question to each other would do what you want. Make sure you explain what you changed.

Comment: @Mast got it. Will do this way next time. This time I 'll add a comment above that current code is already changed due Joseph's comments

Comment: Again, do not change your code in the question. Not with a comment, not with anything. Leave the code in the question as-is.

Comment: @Mast if you take so active part by editing my question, maybe you will suggest me anything about my approach? What the pitfalls may I meet with it? May you compare my approach with the one in the article above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ActionCreator.js**

- Why write a class for when you just export a single instance? When one makes a class, one expects to be able to make multiple instances. This doesn't. You can just roll with object literals. You could even just write functions and just export them.
- `service` is undefined. Where is it?

**todo-service.js**

- Same as above, why write a class?

**WebSocketWrapper.js**

- Same as above, why write a class? Even more interesting is that you have "tracking variables" (`reqId` and `responseDeffers`) outside the class.
- Not sure how you'd benefit with `let` in you code. You're declaring them at the very top of a function scope. `var` would have sufficed.

Just because JS has ES6 doesn't mean you have to use classes, `let` and all the new stuff.